# getElementById vs. getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript

Basic question.

```
document.getElementById("yy").onmouseover = hi;
//document.getElementsByTagName("li").onmouseover = hi;
...
```

In this example, http://jsfiddle.net/8fURz/1/ why does the first line work, but not the second line (when it is un-commented, of course)?

I know I can do this easily with jQuery, just wonderin...

Comment: Try: http://jsfiddle.net/8fURz/2/ `.getElementsByTagName()` returns an array of objects, while `.getElementById()` returns an object, so you have to select a specific index with the former, but not the latter (since it's single by nature).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `document.getElementsByTagName("li")` return a `NodeList`, you need to bind event handler to every element of the `NodeList`.

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i= 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].onmouseover = hi;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because getElementsByTagName returns a *collection* of DOM elements. Of course a collection doesn't have a click event. If you want to bind an event to every element in the collection, you would simply loop through the collection and add a handler to every DOM element in the collection.