# getElementsByTagName does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbytagname, selectors-api

Can someone please explain why my code is not working !!

When I get the element By Id it works perfectly fine. But the same method with getElementsByTagName() does not.

Also if I use querySelector(), it works. However if I use querySelectorAll() the same error returns.

test.html:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined

here is my code:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p id="par">Hello World</p>

<script>
var par = document.getElementById('par');
par.style.color = "red"
var heading = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
heading.style.color = "red"
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `heading[0].style.color = "red"`

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Some of the routines return a single item, others return a list. Also, please fix the typo in your question title.

Comment: In case the function name isn't clear enough: `getElementSSSSByTagName` while `getElementById` doesn't have a 's'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135403/getelementbyid-vs-getelementsbytagname There should be a better dupe, but this is all I can find

Comment: Let's see, I'm sure you had your console open, and saw the error, which would have been "cannot read property 'color' of undefined". That obviously means that `heading.style` is undefined. To see why, examine, using the devtools console you know so well, the variable `heading`. You will see that it is an **array**, which obviously does not have a `style` property--its **elements** (such as `heading[0]`) do. This is basic debugging, which you're going to need to learn if you hope to ever create a meaningful application without asking a question on SO every time you run into a little roadbump.

Comment: Thanks all @torazaburo can you please explain where exactly it shows that the heading variable is an array?

Comment: See Pankaj Kumar's informative answer. The square brackets around the `<h1>` element indicate that it's one element in an array.

Comment: right I understand.. I did not know you could type directly into the console and get what it is returning at every step. Thanks all

Comment: I **strongly** recommend that you drop everything else you are doing and learn how to use the console.

Comment: @torazaburo right, what I just learned is already extremely useful..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As you can clearly see `document,getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements, not a single element.

So you have to follow proper indexing otherwise it will throw an exception as in your case.

Comment: Did you type into the console to get that result ?

Comment: The lines starting with `>` are the ones he typed in.

Comment: Yes...this is the chromes console

Comment: @torazaburo....sir in this structure these elements are actually the objects...so whether you refer it as an element or object it does not matter..