# Javascript remove DOM element if exists

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a button with an event listener that appends items to the DOM when clicked. 
I'd like to add a function that clears those appended elements on subsequent button clicks.

Here's what I've tried but keep getting "div is undefined".

```
function appendStuff(data) {
   for ( let i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    let body = document.querySelector('body');
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    let id = document.createElement('h1');
    div.appendChild(id)
    body.appendChild(div)
  }
};

button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  clearDOM(), appendStuff()
});

function clearDOM() {
if (div.document.body) {
let removeDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
document.body.removeChild(removeDiv);
}
};
```

I suppose a work-around would be to disable the button after a single click.

I think the catch here is that the first time the button is clicked there will not be a div element in the DOM. That seems to be what is throwing the error. Was hoping the If statement would get around that.

Comment: can you share the append method

Comment: what is `div.document.body`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny it's testing if there is a div in the document.body, isn't it?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of nodes. You'll have to remove them one by one.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576698/getelementsbytagname-does-not-seem-to-work.

Comment: It would be slightly better practice to create a `DocumentFragment` and insert all the nodes at once.

Comment: Do not pollute your questions with EDIT notations. No-one cares when or how you edited your question, and if they do, they can check the edit history. If you want to respond to a commenter who asked you to add information saying you have done so, then do that in comments.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks. would what is described here work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955229/remove-all-child-elements-of-a-dom-node-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the `div` elements might not be the best idea, instead try to use a more specific selector like a class.

While creating the div, add a class to that and in the clear method remove all divs with the class

```js
function appendStuff(data) {
  let body = document.querySelector('body');
  let ct = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    let id = document.createElement('h1');
    div.className = 'my-class';
    div.appendChild(id)
    ct.appendChild(div)
  }
  body.appendChild(ct)
};


button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  clearDOM(), appendStuff([{}, {}, {}, {}])
});

function clearDOM() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.my-class');
  Array.from(divs).forEach((div) => div.remove())

};
```

```css
h1 {
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: @torazaburo you can try out the demo :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove - Need to have a look at browser support(only in edge) - else need to use `div.parentNode.removeChild(div)`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple issues.

```
function clearDOM() {
  if (div.document.body) {
    let removeDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    document.body.removeChild(removeDiv);
  }
};
```

First, indent your code properly. Also, functions do not need a terminating semi-colon.

Anyway, in the above, `div.document.body` does not mean anything; `div` is an undefined variable. What are you trying to check for? Remove this `if` condition.

Second, `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of nodes, and you can't `removeChild` that directly. You'll have to loop:

```
let removeDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (let i=0; i<removeDivs.length; i++) document.body.removeChild(removeDivs[i]);
```

Although it will not affect the way your code works, it is better practice to create all the new elements in advance and insert them all at once, using `DocumentFragment`.

```
function appendStuff(data) {
  let frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

  for ( let i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    let id = document.createElement('h1');
    div.appendChild(id);
    frag.appendChild(div);
  }

  document.body.appendChild(frag);
}
```

By the way, you don't need to use `querySelector` to get the body. It's right there in `document.body`.